# How to change background/foreground color of a `gedit()` or `gcombobox()` input box?

Tags: r, colors, gwidgets, background-foreground

Consider the following input boxes:

```
w <- gwindow()
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=F)
ed <- gedit(cont=g)
cbb <- gcombobox(letters, editable=T, use_completion=T, cont=g)
```

How can I make the background of the `gedit()`/`gcombobox()` input box of red color and the foreground (the text itself) of white color, when it contains the string `asdf`?

Comment: If `e` is the entry widget, something like this should work: `e$widget$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], "red")`. You can clear the modification by passing in `NULL`.

Comment: What about the color of the foreground (i.e. the text itself). Can that be changed?

Comment: There are these methods: `modifyBase`, `modifyText`, `modifyBg`, `modifyFg` (and maybe others) to adjust these things. I think `Fg` is what you want.

Comment: And what about a `gcombobox()`? I tried `cbb <- gcombobox(letters, editable=T, use_completion=T, cont=ggroup(cont=w))` then `cbb$widget$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], "red")`, but nothing happens.

Comment: I would think you need to get the entry widget in the combobox to modify as above. I have this total hack: `cb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]` to get this for an editable combo box. Maybe there is a method to do this properly.

Comment: It's `modifyText`. Works great.

Comment: `cbb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], "red")` does indeed work for a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the following does the job, and you can replace `red` with`#FF6666` (Light Faded Red) or whatever color:

```
addHandlerKeystroke(ed, function(h,...){
    if(svalue(ed)=="asdf"){ 
        ed$widget$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], "red") 
        ed$widget$modifyText(GtkStateType["normal"], "white") 
    } else {
        ed$widget$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], NULL)
        ed$widget$modifyText(GtkStateType["normal"], NULL) 
    }
})
```

For `gcombobox()` it's slightly different:

```
addHandlerChanged(cbb, function(h,...){
    if(svalue(cbb)=="asdf"){ 
        cbb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], "red")
        cbb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]$modifyText(GtkStateType["normal"], "white")
    } else {
        cbb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]$modifyBase(GtkStateType["normal"], NULL)
        #cbb$widget$getChildren()[[1]]$modifyText(GtkStateType["normal"], NULL)
    }
})
```